# How to access associative arrays in bash

Tags: bash, associative-array

I'm having trouble accessing keys in my associative bash array.

```
postgresql=(["host"]="foo" ["user"]="bar")

echo "USER: ${postgresql["user"]}" # bar
echo "HOST: ${postgresql["host"]}" # bar
```

As you can see I get back `bar` for both keys. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `declare -A` to define it:

```
$ declare -A postgresql=([host]='foo' [user]='bar')
$ echo "USER: ${postgresql["user"]}"
USER: bar
$ echo "HOST: ${postgresql["host"]}"
HOST: foo
```

Note associative arrays were introduced in Bash 4, so that they won't work if you are not using at least that version. More info in [BashGuide -> Associative arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays).

I quote [chepner's very useful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748776/how-to-access-associative-arrays-in-bash#comment40261967_25748890) below:

> Associative arrays were introduced in version 4, and so unavailable in
>   the default bash in Mac OS X. Note without a declaration, `postgresql`
>   is a regular array, and the index is treated as an arithmetic
>   expression, so the string "index" is treated as a variable whose value
>   is 0 if the variable is unset. Your code just sets the 0th element
>   multiple times. –  chepner 8 mins ago

Comment: This gives me `declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]`

Comment: @kyledecot same here (on a Mac); replace `-A` with `-a`

Comment: `-a` is for indexed array, which version of bash are you using?

Comment: @kyledecot it needs bash 4. Could you try with `typeset -A`? More info in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Comment: `GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`. Using `typeset -A` also gives me the invalid option error

Comment: @kyledecot then, unfortunately, you cannot use associative arrays. It is a functionality that was added in bash 4.

Comment: Associative arrays were introduced in version 4, and so unavailable in the default `bash` in Mac OS X. Note without a declaration, `postgresql` is a regular array, and the index is treated as an arithmetic expression, so the string "index" is treated as a variable whose value is 0 if the variable is unset. Your code just sets the 0th element multiple times.

Comment: @chepner many thanks for the explanation. I added your comment in the answer so that it is more visible. Of course, feel free to edit (or remove).

Comment: @kyledecot in 15 minutes start's the Apple-event, and the Yosemite OS X (i hope) will contains bash 4+) :) ;)

Comment: @jm666 I am googling and cannot find what they decided about bash version on Yosemite OS X. Do you have any leak? :)